# how multiple dates can be selected from full calender and pass it as an input parameter to my java class

Tags: jquery

How can i get multiple dates from full calender to pass to a java class by dragging over the cells. Now i get only single date from day click function? can you please explain me hoe to do the same

Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you can share the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: thanks for your response. i had fix that isuue. here is my code

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your response. i had fix that isuue. here is my code
$(document).ready(function() {

```
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view){ 
            $(this).css('background-color','#F4BA4D');

        },
        defaultDate: moment(),
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        firstDay:1,
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {              
            $('#createEventModal #date').val(start, end);                           
            $('#createEventModal').modal('show');
            $("#temp_123").val(start.format()+'\tto\t'+end.format()); $(this).css('background-color','#F4BA4D');
             var dateVal = $("#temp_123").val();
                $('#date-display').text(dateVal);

        },
```